# How to delay the opacity transition of an element using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am planning to create a loading page (fake loading page), in which I have done already, also with the HTML.  The problem is the page is already loaded, and the loading screen appears right after the page is loaded.

Loading Screen Tutorial [here](https://ihatetomatoes.net/create-custom-preloading-screen/).

Webpage HTML:

```js
<!-- JavaScripts go here -->
<script>
setTimeout(function() {
document.getElementById("loading").className = "loaded";
}, 5000);
</script>
<script>
var year = Today.getYear()
var month = Today.getMonth()
var date = Today.getDate()
var day = Today.getDay()

if(year < 1000){
year += 1900
}

var monthArray = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", 

"July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December") 
      
var dayArray = new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday", 

"Thursday","Friday","Saturday")

document.write( monthArray[month] + " " + date + ", " + year + " (" + dayArray[day] + 

")" )
</script>
<script>
function startTime() {
    var today=new Date();
    var h=today.getHours();
    var m=today.getMinutes();
    var s=today.getSeconds();
    var ampm = " PM "
    if (h < 12){
    ampm = " AM "
    }
    if (h > 12){
    h -= 12
    }
    if (h < 10){
    h = "0" + h
    }
    if (m < 10){
    m = m
    }
    if (s < 10){
    s = s
    }
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = h+" : "+m+" : "+s + ampm;
    var t = setTimeout(function(){startTime()},500);
}

function checkTime(i) {
    if (i<10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}
</script>
```

```css
<!-- Main Styles go here -->
<style>
body {
    background: url(IMAGE_bkgnd_DARK_BROWN_PAPER.gif) repeat 0 0;
}
</style>
<!-- ID Styles go here -->
<style>
#navBar {
    opacity: 0.75;
}
#navBar:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
#mHFloat {
    float: left;
}
#Headings {
    margin: 0cm 3cm 0cm 3cm;
    opacity: 0.85;
    border-top-left-radius: 12px 7px;
    border-top-right-radius: 12px 7px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #CCCCCC;
}
#mWbLogo {
    padding-left: 10px;
    float: left;
}
#mHeadText {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    float: left;
}
#Body {
    margin: 0cm 3cm 0cm 3cm;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 12px 7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 12px 7px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #AAAAAA;
}
#Footer {
    margin: 0cm 3cm 0cm 3cm;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #CCCCCC;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
}
#Credits {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
</style>
<!-- Class Styles go here -->
<style>
.active {
    text-decoration: none;
}
a.active:link {
    color: #59AA0C;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #FEDCBA;
}
a.active:visited {
    color: #70AB1D;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #FEDCBA;
}
a.active:hover {
    color: #80CD2E;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #FF0C5DE;
}
.inactive {
    text-decoration: none;
}
a.inactive:link {
    color: #59AA0C;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px outset transparent;
}
a.inactive:visited {
    color: #70AB1D;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px outset transparent;
}
a.inactive:hover {
    color: #80CD2E;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px outset #ACFFC7;
}
a.inactive:active {
    color: #80CD2E;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px inset #ACFFC7;
}
br.brShort {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.hrMargin {
    margin: 0cm 3cm 0cm 3cm;;
}
</style>
```

```html
<body onload="startTime()" id="loading" class="loading1">
<div id="loader-wrapper">
    <div id="loader"></div>
    
    <div class="loader-section section-left"></div>
    <div class="loader-section section-right"></div>
</div>
<div id="Headings" class="mHeader" style="border:2px outset gold; 

background:#DDDDDD;">
<br class="brShort">
<div id="mHFloat">
<img id="mWbLogo" src="earth-world-wide-web-13597096.jpg" alt="Web Logo" width="7.5%" 

height="5%">
<strong id="mHeadText" style="font-family:Open Sans"> World Wide Web </strong>
</div>
<div id="navBar" align="right">
<font face="Ubuntu Condensed" size="5">
<span>
<a href="#" onclick="window.location.reload()" title="Go to the 'Home' page" 

class="active">&nbspHome&nbsp</a>
</span>
<span>
<a href="#" title="Go to the 'About Us' page" class="inactive">&nbspAbout Us&nbsp</a>
</span>
<span>
<a href="#" title="Go to the 'Contact Us' page" class="inactive">&nbspContact 

Us&nbsp</a>
</span>
</font>
</div>
<br class="brShort">
</div>
<br class="brShort">
<hr class="hrMargin">
<br class="brShort">
<div id="Body" class="mBody" style="background:#EEFFEF">
<br class="brShort">
<h2 style="padding-left:50px; padding-right:25px; font-family:Oswald">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
<br class="brShort">
<p style="padding-left:50px; padding-right:50px; text-align:justify; font-

family:Roboto">some text</p>
</font>
</div>
<br>
<div id="Footer" class="mFooter" style="border:1px outset gold; background:#70AB1D; 

font-family:Montserrat">
<span style="color:White">Time:</span>
<span id="time" style="color:White"></span>
<span id="date" style="color:White; float:Right">
</span>
<span style="color:White; float:Right">Date:&nbsp</span>
</div>
<br style="display:block; margin-top:1px">
<div id="Credits" align="center">
<p style="font-family:Ubuntu Condensed">Images and fonts came from Google
<br>
JavaScripts (Date and Time) by ProgLogic</p>
</div>
</body>
```

I didn't include the loading thing because in the example 'snippet' thing, the screen is stuck in the loading screen.

Comment: How does your title relates to your problem ("The problem is ....") ?

Comment: We don't need the **whole page** JUST the code that relates to the issue..

Comment: oh... What I mean is to delay all the elements in the page except the loading thing.  I want to 'fade in' the load, but without the fade, everything is fine.  The elements (except the loading thing) are already loaded, so the load will show up after the element is loaded.

Comment: @LloydDominic A loading page is **necessary only if** your main content is **very large** (A game for example). I think you should create **two pages**, one for loading page and one for your main content. Your loading page will load your main page (by using `<iframe>` or `XMLHttpRequest`). Your loading page should be small.

Comment: Try using transition delays https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-delay